# Counting correlated checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If I have a row of checkboxes which indicate especially important columns in a sheet, how do I count for each row how many of the relevant checkboxes are ticked.

For example:

[image: Three rows of checkboxes]

If the top row tells me that I am especially interested in the answers in columns 3, 6, 9, 13 & 15, I would like for each row to do a calculation that tell me how many of the corresponding checkboxes in that row are NOT selected.

In this example, running the calculation on row two should produce a result of 2, as the checkboxes in this row are not selected in the case of the 'important' columns 6 and 13.

The same calculation performed on row three should produce the result 0, as all of the 'important' columns have their checkboxes selected in row 3.

I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require a lot of brute force ANDing or ORing, since the columns are likely to change fairly often. A good answer would have something like the form:

"For this row, how many of the checkboxes between in columns 1 to 19 are unchecked where the corresponding checkbox in row 1 is checked"

(If it helps, the spreadsheet is for comparing product features between different offerings. there's a product on every row, while each column represents a feature. I want to be able to select the 'must have' features in row one, and get a number for each product that tells me how many of the key features it is missing. The contract goes to the reasonably-priced product that returns 0).

tia

Comment: Hi @Andy Wilson, I have formulated an answer below. Kindly check if it works on you.

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly what I was looking for - terse and precise.

Comment: Hi @Andy Wilson, thank you for your reply. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

Since we are comparing 1st row vs another row, a way to solve this is by using `ARRAYFORMULA` and subtracting 1st row with the current row.

Since ticked checkboxes are `TRUE`, it has a numerical value of `1`. And if we subtract 1st row and the current row, (the unticked current row is `0`) then it will result into `1`.

With this in mind, we just need to count how many are there that results to `1`.

#### Final Formula:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(C$1:U$1 - C2:U2), "=1")`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Since row 3's 3rd column is not ticked, result should be `1` instead of `0` which you mentioned mistakenly in your post above.